# How to say "any_instance" "should_receive" any number of times in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, mocking, mocha.js

I've got an import controller in rails that imports several csv files with multiple records into my database. I would like to test in RSpec if the records are actually saved by using RSpec:

```
<Model>.any_instance.should_receive(:save).at_least(:once)
```

However i get the error saying:

```
The message 'save' was received by <model instance> but has already been received by <another model instance>
```

A contrived example of the controller:

```
rows = CSV.parse(uploaded_file.tempfile, col_sep: "|")

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    rows.each do |row| 
    mutation = Mutation.new
    row.each_with_index do |value, index| 
      Mutation.send("#{attribute_order[index]}=", value)
    end
  mutation.save          
end
```

Is it possible to test this using RSpec or is there any workaround?

Comment: What version of RSpec are you using and what's the failure message you're seeing?

Comment: rspec (2.8.0) and the message is: The message 'save' was received by <model instance> but has already been received by <another model instance>

Comment: That's the expected behavior. The point of any_instance is to not have to know which single instance is expecting something, but it still constrains it to one instance.

Comment: It's the expected behaviour - granted- but it's not very useful if you want to test this. And there doesn't seem to be any other method, like "many_instances" that relaxes the constraint of one instance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There's a new syntax for this:

```
expect_any_instance_of(Model).to receive(:save).at_least(:once)
```

Comment: The designers of rspec discourage the use of `expect_any_instance_of`. Here's a [link to the doc](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance).

Comment: @TylerCollier yeah, I totally agree. From that doc: "Using this feature is often a design smell. It may be that your test is trying to do too much or that the object under test is too complex."

Comment: This actually does not work for me; same error as original question.  using RSpec 3.3.3.

Comment: Then it sounds like a legit failure. There are two instances that are receiving the message.

Answer (score 55):

Here's a better answer that avoids having to override the :new method:

```
save_count = 0
<Model>.any_instance.stub(:save) do |arg|
    # The evaluation context is the rspec group instance,
    # arg are the arguments to the function. I can't see a
    # way to get the actual <Model> instance :(
    save_count+=1
end
.... run the test here ...
save_count.should > 0
```

Seems that the stub method can be attached to any instance w/o the constraint, and the do block can make a count that you can check to assert it was called the right number of times.

Update - new rspec version requires this syntax:

```
save_count = 0
allow_any_instance_of(Model).to receive(:save) do |arg|
    # The evaluation context is the rspec group instance,
    # arg are the arguments to the function. I can't see a
    # way to get the actual <Model> instance :(
    save_count+=1
end
.... run the test here ...
save_count.should > 0
```

Comment: Ah nice using stub on any_instance! Looks nicer and more dynamic than my solution.

Comment: Even though yours is less hacky, I don't like counters, by proxying to a class method [here][http://stackoverflow.com/a/15038406/619510] I kept the same syntax.

Comment: Brilliant! Take +1 for that. :D

Answer (score 16):

This is Rob's example using RSpec 3.3, which no longer supports  `Foo.any_instance`. I found this useful when in a loop creating objects

```
# code (simplified version)
array_of_hashes.each { |hash| Model.new(hash).write! }

# spec
it "calls write! for each instance of Model" do 
  call_count = 0
  allow_any_instance_of(Model).to receive(:write!) { call_count += 1 }

  response.process # run the test
  expect(call_count).to eq(2)
end
```

Answer (score 15):

I finally managed to make a test that works for me:

```
  mutation = FactoryGirl.build(:mutation)
  Mutation.stub(:new).and_return(mutation)
  mutation.should_receive(:save).at_least(:once)
```

The stub method returns one single instance that receives the save method multiple times. Because it is a single instance i can drop the `any_instance` method and use the `at_least` method normally.

Answer (score 11):

Stub like this

```
User.stub(:save) # Could be any class method in any class
User.any_instance.stub(:save) { |*args| User.save(*args) }
```

Then expect like this:

```
# User.any_instance.should_receive(:save).at_least(:once)
User.should_receive(:save).at_least(:once)
```

This is a simplification of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mmacedo/5018850), to use `any_instance`, since you don't need to proxy to the original method. Refer to that gist for other uses.

Comment: Excellent. Proxying the method through to a known instance works great. You could just as easily stub(:save) on a test double instead of the User class.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Just use `allow` and `allow_any_instance_of` instead of `stub` and `any_instance.stub` since the former are now deprecated (see: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#settings-mocks-or-stubs-on-any-instance-of-a-class)

Answer (score 5):

My case was a bit different, but I ended up at this question to figured to drop my answer here too. In my case I wanted to stub any instance of a given class. I got the same error when I used `expect_any_instance_of(Model).to`. When I changed it to `allow_any_instance_of(Model).to`, my problem was solved.

Check out the documentation for some more background: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#settings-mocks-or-stubs-on-any-instance-of-a-class

Comment: Thank you! That's the most useful answer for me in this thread.

Comment: From the docs: "The rspec-mocks API is designed for individual object instances, but this feature operates on entire classes of objects. As a result there are some semantically confusing edge cases. For example in `expect_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).twice` it isn't clear whether each specific instance is expected to receive `name` twice, or if two receives total are expected. (It's the former.)"

Answer (score 0):

You may try to count the number of `new` on the class. That is not actually tests the number of `save`s but may be enough

```rb
    expect(Mutation).to receive(:new).at_least(:once)
```

If there is the only expectation of how many times it was saved. Then you probably want to use `spy()` instead of fully functioning factory, as in `Harm de Wit` own answer

```rb
    allow(Mutation).to receive(:new).and_return(spy)
    ...
    expect(Mutation.new).to have_received(:save).at_least(:once)
```