# Rspec Mocks on any_instance with exactly(n) times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to use Mocks in rspec tests like.

```
klass.any_instance.should_receive(:save).exactly(2).times.and_return(true)
```

but I get an error message like:

**'The message "save" was received by <#Object> but has already been received by <#Object>'**

Temporary I use stub but for accuracy want to use mocks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to say "any\_instance" "should\_receive" any number of times in RSpec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800992/how-to-say-any-instance-should-receive-any-number-of-times-in-rspec)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-6/docs/message-expectations/expect-a-message-on-any-instance-of-a-class) of `any_instance.should_receive` is:

```
Use any_instance.should_receive to set an expectation that one (and only one)
instance of a class receives a message before the example is completed.
```

So you have specified that exactly one object should receive the `save` call two times, and not that 2 objects should receive the `save` call one time.

If you want to count the calls done by different instances you'll have to be [creative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800992/how-to-say-any-instance-should-receive-any-number-of-times-in-rspec) like:

```
save_count = 0
klass.any_instance.stub(:save) { save_count+=1 }
# run test
save_count.should == 2
```

Comment: i want two different object to should_receive(:save) in one example. Actually i am creating 'n' new object through looping and want to test it hit the save method. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You have to use my second example then